# foreman dashboard doesn't open

Tags: linux, apache, foreman

when i try to load dashboard using my IP, it says
"website is online, but not accepting connections"

when i try elinks on the host system, it gives ssl error

when i use curl it gives:

[root@foreman ~]# curl https://192.168.187.128  -k
You are being [redirected](https://192.168.187.128/users/login).[root@foreman ~]#

I checked, port 80 and 443 are listening, i have disabled selinux as well.

Comment: Perhaps you have a firewall configured?

Comment: Bingo! This was the issue I had. Thank you for your time Dominic